# about the order of a finite extension of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions, cyclotomic-fields

If $|K| = q$ and $(n,q) = 1$ and $F$ is a splitting field of $x^n - 1$ over $K$, then $[F:K]$ is the least positive integer $k$ such that $n \mid q^k - 1$.

My idea: Since $K$ is finite, we know that $q = p^r$ for some prime number $p$ and natural number $r$. Now let $m = [F:K]$, and I am trying to prove that $n$ divides $p^{rm} - 1$. It is well known that $F$ is also the splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^{rm}} - x$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (so over $K$). Furthermore, $F$ is a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. I collected all this information but I am not sure how to conclude my argument. Hints?

Comment: The missing link may be to use that $F^*$ is a cyclic group of order $q^k-1$. Therefore it has an element $\alpha$ of order $n$. Show that the powers of $\alpha$ are the zeros of $x^n-1$.

Comment: The nonzero elements of the field $\Bbb F_q^k$ are the $(q^k-1)$-th roots of unity. You are after the least $k$ so that $n$-th roots of unity must be $(q^k-1)$-th roots of unity.

Comment: Mind you, I have answered variants of this question in so many guises that I have lost count. Once for finding the irreducible reps for $C_n$ over $K$, on another occasion to factor cyclotomic polynomials over $K$ etc. As I am also militantly anti-duplicate, I should not post an answer to your question. May be I can guide you to getting there :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Assuming $F = \mathbb{Z}_p(u)$. Let $\zeta$ be an $n$-th root of unity such that $\zeta = u^H$ and $H$ is minimal. Then clearly $\zeta$ is primitive, which implies that $u^H$ generates all the roots of $x^n - 1$. This implies that $p^{rk} - 1$ divides $n\cdot H$, why is it equal?

Comment: Assuming $u$ is a generator of $F^*$ then $H=(q^k-1)/n$. This is because of the rule familiar from  the theory of cyclic groups. If $c$ is a generator of a cyclic group of order $m$, then the order of $c^k$ is equal to $m/\gcd(k,m)$. Here $u$ has order $q^k-1$.

Comment: But, I don't think you need to know the value of $H$ at all. As $n\mid q^k-1$ the group $\langle u\rangle=F^*$ will have an element $\zeta$ of order $n$. Because $n\nmid q^\ell-1$ for $\ell<k$, the smaller fields cannot have elements of order $n$.

Comment: Of course, you then also need to make the observation that some roots of $x^n-1$ must have order exactly $n$. One way of seeing that is to observe that the zeros of $x^n-1$ form a group. As a subgroup of a cyclic group that group has to be cyclic itself.

Comment: Actually, if $n\mid q^k-1$ then $x^n-1$ is a factor of $x^{q^k-1}-1$, which is, in turn, a factor of $x^{q^k}-x$. Hence the splitting field of the last polynomial also contains all the zeros of $x^n-1$.

Comment: For the other direction, you can use the fact that $\gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)=x^{\gcd(n,m)}-1$. Therefore the field consisting of zeros of $x^{q^\ell}-x$ will contain the zeros of $x^n-1$ if and only if $x^n-1$ is factor of $x^{q^\ell}-x$ if and only if $n\mid q^\ell-1$. Heck! Looks like we need not use cyclicity at all if we have that fact about $\gcd(x^n-1,x^m-1)$. Have you seen that?

Comment: And, sorry about the bumbling. I just got started in trying to prove this without using the cyclicity (in case you haven't proved that in class yet).

Comment: you're right I don't need H. I get it now! I am good with the cyclicity I just did not remember the result about the order of a power of a generator.

Comment: yes, I have not seen the argument you mentioned about the other direction but the steps are not hard to check.